# UTF-8 encoding when reading from database (C#)

Tags: c#, database, encoding, utf-8

I have a C# program that reads data from a database and outputs it to a text file.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, conn);
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (rdr.HasRows)
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            string toStr = rdr[i].ToString();

            // ...etc.
```

One line in particular keeps giving me trouble.  Here is what it looks like in the database:

```
Signed 8-bit 2’s-compliment
```

Here is what it looks like in my output file:

```
Signed 8-bit 2â€™s-compliment
```

I figured that I could fix this by taking the encoding into account.  So I changed my code to convert the text to UTF-8:

```
string toStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rdr[i].ToString()));
```

Which results in:

```
Signed 8-bit 2ï¿½s-compliment
```

However, if I do THIS...

```
string toStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Signed 8-bit 2â€™s-compliment"));
```

...it works perfectly.

```
Signed 8-bit 2’s-compliment
```

Could `rdr[i].toString()` be the problem?  My guess is that when it converts the object to a string, it screws up the encoding of the `â€™` character, which prevents me from being able to convert it properly to an apostrophe.  But I don't think I can avoid using `toString()` there.  So what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is on the database's end. Presuming SQL Server, take a look at this link regarding [Collation and Unicode Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx). Basically, your data may not be returned in the format you're thinking.

In general, SQL supports UTF-16, not UTF-8 - so provided the data is returned properly, `ToString()` should decode it properly, as .NET strings are formatted UTF-16.

Also, if you don't particularly care for that specific character, you can just update your database record and set a "normal" apostrophe for that line of text.